# Flex box row wrap not working in safari. Tried multiple prefixes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My flex box is working just great in Chrome , but not safari and firefox. I've tried a lot of different prefixes for the webkit. Doesn't work :(

Do I need to do something with the flex-items? Or is it just that there's something wrong with my flex-container?

Just noticed there is different behavior depending on if " -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; " is commented out or not. Although, not the right behavior either way. When its not commented, there's a verticle column all the way on the left. And when it is commented, its just a row with everything right next to each other across the top of the page

Also noticed when "display: -webkit-box;" is in there, no matter if webkit-flex-flow is commented or not, then the display shows all the things next to each other in a list. But if that is not there, then when webkit-flex-flow is there, there's a vertical column. and when it is commented, there is a row column.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  /*display: -webkit-box;*/
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /*-webkit-box-flex-flow: row wrap;*/
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;

  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {

  padding: 0px;
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  line-height: 10px;
  color: white;

}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="flex-item">
  <a href="#/thing"><img src="img/thing.svg"></br>thing thing</a>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item">
  <a href="#/thing"><img src="img/thing.svg"></br>thing/<br>thing</a>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item">
  <a href="#/thing"><img src="img/thing.svg"></br>thing</a>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item">
  <a href="#/thing"><img src="img/thing.svg"></br>thing</a>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item">
  <a href="#/thing"><img src="img/thing.svg"></br>thing</a>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item">
  <a href="#/thing"><img src="img/thing-thing.svg"></br>thing thing</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which version? safari supports 7+

Comment: Yeah, v. 8 something :( 

Just noticed there is different behavior depending on if "  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; " is commented out or not. Although, not the right behavior either way. When its not commented, there's a verticle column all the way on the left. And when it is commented, its just a row with everything right next to each other across the top of the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wasn't working thanks to the absence of

```
-webkit-flex: 1 1 15em;
-moz-flex: 1 1 15em;
flex: 1 1 15em;
```

in .flex-item.

Hence why it was working so well in chrome, but not firefox or safari. Chrome just gets this stuff, I suppose.

A great perk to this that solved another problem (kind of) is that now the images automatically resize themselves, in addition to moving. But have to tweak that a little more to be robust enough for the differences between mobile/web views

Answer (score 1):

I have faced sometimes that separating the shorthand code into multiple works in safari browsers.

So, try the following:

```
-webkit-flex-flow: row;
-webkit-flex-flow: wrap;
```

Instead of:

```
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrp;
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but it turns out the culprit was not having some things in .flex-item. :0 but, appreciate it :)